# Stored Procedure not returning affected rows when INSERT is not executed

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlcommand

I have a stored procedure which is supposed to do an insert but checks first if the primary key is already used by having an `IF NOT EXISTS` before the insert.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ...)
INSERT INTO ...
```

So I generate the primary key via code because it is used as a token. I now want to catch the very unlikely case that the generated key already exists in the database by looking at the return value of the `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` method which is supposed to be the count of affected rows.

If the insert is executed the method does return '1' as the count of affected rows but if the insert is not executed because of the `IF` statement the stored procedure does not return a count of affected rows at all. It simply says 'Command(s) completed successfully.' in SQL Server Management Studio and therefore the `ExecuteNonQuery` method returns -1.

Why is this and can I change this behavior somehow or is this just how it works?

Comment: The return value is the number of rows affected by the `INSERT` - what do you expect to get back if **no** `INSERT` even happens? Since nothing happens - nothing gets returned - seem pretty logical to me .... no `INSERT` means : no rows affected by that non-existing `INSERT` ....

Comment: Inside your SP, use @@rowcount and return it as output parameter.

Comment: @marc_s as you wrote "no rows affected by that non-existing INSERT". Thats why I expacted it to say 0 rows affacted instead of Command(s) completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You probable have NOCOUNT set to ON...

You can test this in your management studio with the following queries:

Example **NOCOUNT OFF:**

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[table1]
```

Returns `(n row(s) affected)`

Example **NOCOUNT ON:**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[table1]
```

Returns `Command(s) completed successfully.`

Answer (score 0):

Try a return variable for when the insert is not executed, like this:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @m_norecord int = 0      

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT...)
INSERT INTO...
ELSE 
SELECT @m_norecord 

END
```